How does Microsoft virtual network adapter work?
A noob question. Let's say the laptop is connected to the router via a wired connection. Laptop's IPv4 address is 192.168.88.14 and the Default gateway is 192.168.88.1. The Wireless LAN adapter local area connection appears in the connections list when the Wi-Fi is on. Its IPv4 address is 192.168.137.1 with the Default gateway left blank. Seems like the virtual network adapter creates, well.... a virtual pool of 192.168.137.xxx IP-addresses with a 192.168.137.1 reserved for itself. Is the network of devices connected to Hotspot perceived as a separate network so the traffic from 192.168.137.x is then directed to 192.168.137.1, then to 192.168.88.14 and further down the network? What are the inner workings behind all of that?
Just trying to get a basic understanding of how the virtual network adapter works
